# Simple webscraping issue- rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to web scrape the data table on "https://stats.premierlacrosseleague.com/pll-team-table". I've tried multiple different ways of achieving this and keep ending up with the same result that my table is empty? Does anyone have any solutions? I posted my code down below, thanks in advance!

```
library(rvest)

pll <- read_html("https://stats.premierlacrosseleague.com/pll-team-table")

table<- pll%>%html_nodes(".jss820")%>%html_text()

data_table<- data.frame(table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, scraping in that way will not work, because the data is loaded dynamically; after the page has loaded. If you right-click the page, click 'inspect element', go to the 'network' tab, and refresh the page, you can see the XHR requests being made.

One of those requests is to https://api.stats.premierlacrosseleague.com/v1.00/teams-stats/all/2020, which contains the table you want, in JSON form. The below code reads that table with [jsonlite](https://jeroen.cran.dev/jsonlite/index.html) (which gives a nested `list` in R) and turns it into a `data.frame` using [unnest_wider](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/hoist.html):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

url <- "https://api.stats.premierlacrosseleague.com/v1.00/teams-stats/all/2020"
data_list <- jsonlite::read_json(url)

data_table <- tibble(data = data_list) %>% 
  unnest_wider(data)
```

This gives

```
# A tibble: 7 x 55
  scores faceoffPct shotPct twoPointShotPct twoPointShotsOn… clearPct ridesPct savePct shortHandedPct
   <int>      <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>          <int>
1     20      0.488   0.339           0.5               3.83    0.9     0        0.644              0
2     21      0.490   0.230           0.6               1.93    0.961   0.12     0.588              0
3     16      0.452   0.238           0.5               1.75    0.98    0.0769   0.623              0
4     25      0.667   0.293           0.545             2.73    0.932   0.0196   0.591              0
5     28      0.333   0.184           0.6               1.52    0.940   0.0263   0.559              0
6     17      0.523   0.239           0.8               4.2     0.935   0.0755   0.545              0
7     13      0.696   0.351           0.571             2.43    1       0.0870   0.682              0
# … with 46 more variables
```